# GitHub: How to get `utteranc.es` to work for website discussion

Tags: github, r-markdown, r-distill

My website https://friendly.github.io/HistDataVis/ wants to use the seemingly light weight and useful discussion feature offered by the https://github.com/utterance app.

I believe I have installed it correctly in my repo, https://github.com/friendly/HistDataVis, but it does not appear on the site when built.

I'm stumped on how to determine what the problem is, or how to correct it. Can anyone help?

For reference, here is my setup:

- The website is built in R Studio, using `distill` in rmarkdown.
- I created `utterances.html` with the standard JS code recommended.

```
    <script>
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        if (!/posts/.test(location.pathname)) {
          return;
        }
        
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.src = "https://utteranc.es/client.js";
        script.setAttribute("repo", "friendly/HistDataVis");
        script.setAttribute("issue-term", "og:title");
        script.setAttribute("crossorigin", "anonymous");
        script.setAttribute("label", "comments ??");
        
        /* wait for article to load, append script to article element */
          var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations, observer) {
            var article = document.querySelector("d-article");
            if (article) {
              observer.disconnect();
              /* HACK: article scroll */
                article.setAttribute("style", "overflow-y: hidden");
              article.appendChild(script);
            }
          });
        
        observer.observe(document.body, { childList: true });
      });
    </script>
```

- In one `Rmd` file, I use `in_header` to insert this into the generated HTML file:

```
    ---
    title: "Discussion"
    date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
    output: 
      distill::distill_article:
        toc: true
        includes:
          in_header: utterances.html
    ---
```

- Also used this in my `_site.yml` file to apply to all `Rmd` files on the site.
- On my GitHub account, I installed utterances under GitHub apps, and gave it repository access to the repo for this site.

[image]

[image]

**Edit2**
Following the solution suggested by @laymonage, I fixed the script. I now get the Comments section on my web page, but get an error, "utterances not installed" when I try to use it.  Yet, utterances *is* installed, as I just checked.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part of your code:

```
if (!/posts/.test(location.pathname)) {
  return;
}
```

Prevents the rest of the script to load because it's always `true`.

The condition checks whether the value of `location.pathname` passes the regular expression test string `posts` and negates it (`!`). That means the condition is `true` if the `location.pathname` (the path name of the current URL, e.g. `/HistDataVis/` for `https://friendly.github.io/HistDataVis/`) does not contain `posts` anywhere in the string. None of the pages on your website has `posts` in the `pathname`, so the script will end there.

It should work if you change `/posts/` to `/HistDataVis` or just remove the `if` block altogether.

---

Alternatively, you can also try [giscus](https://giscus.app), a similar project that uses GitHub Discussions instead of Issues. Someone already made a guide on how to use it with [Distill](https://www.joelnitta.com/posts/2021-11-24_using-giscus/). **Disclaimer:** I'm the developer of giscus.

Comment: This was very helpful, particularly your explanation

Comment: Hmm. I accepted this answer, because the Comments block now appears on my `discussion.html` page.  However, when I tried to use it, I get an error, "Error: utterances is not installed on friendly/HistDataVis. If you own this repo, install the app. Read more about this change in the PR. " Yet, utterances _is_ installed for this repo, as I just verified.